# Is this hypothesis necessary for Abel's Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am reading up on Abel's Theorem from http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/abelthm.pdf.

Screenshot here for convenience:
[image]

Q1): Is it necessary to have the hypothesis that $\sum c_nx^n$ converges for $|x|<1$?

I ask this question since some sources do not have this hypothesis (e.g. 
https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Abel's_Theorem)

Hence I somehow suspect it can be deduced from the fact that $\sum c_n$ converges. I know that the comparison test works $\sum c_nx^n\leq\sum c_n$ works if $c_n$ are nonnegative. I do not know how to deduce it if $c_n$ are possibly negative.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Reference: Hadamard radius (of convergence ) formula.

Comment: sorry to make this question after so much time, but why $\sum c_nx^n\leq\sum c_n$ works if $c_n\geq0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\sum_nc_n $ converges, then $c_n\to0$. In particular, $|c_n|\leq k $ for some $k>0$. Then, if $|z|<1$,
$$
\sum_n|c_nz^n|=\sum_n|c_n|\,|z|^n\leq k\,\sum_n|z|^n=\frac k {1-|z|}.
$$
That is, the series $\sum_nc_nz^n $ converges absolutely for all $z $ with $|z|<1$.

Answer (score 2):

If $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n$ converges, then the radius of convergence $R$ of the power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nz^n$ is at least $1$, because the power series diverges for all $z$ with $|z|>R$. Hence $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nz^n$ converges (in fact converges absolutely) for all $z$ with $|z|<1$.